# How to display results as a line in a picturebox

Tags: vb.net, datatable, picturebox

I want to display results from a datatable as s line in a picturebox using Drawline()

```
Private Sub Yearly_Analysis_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            con3.Open()
            Dim sSQL = "SELECT Mid([Document Name], Len([Document Name]) - 11, 4) As [Year], Count([Year]) As [Totals] FROM Archief Group By Mid([Document Name], Len([Document Name]) - 11, 4) Order By Mid([Document Name], Len([Document Name]) - 11, 4) DESC ;"
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sSQL, con3)
                Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    dt.Load(reader)
                End Using
            End Using

            If dt IsNot Nothing AndAlso dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                        Dim sYear As String = dt.Rows(i)("Year").ToString()
                        Dim sTotals As String = dt.Rows(i)("Totals").ToString()
                Next
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Somebody knows how to display this in a x and y graph?

Answer (score 0):

- You first need to decide the maximum and minimum values for each axes.  If the difference between zero and your min value is much greater than the diff between min and max then you'll probably want to choose a non-zero origin.  Bear in mind that future uses of your class may have negative values.
- Then you need to decide placement of your axes on the canvas, from that you can determine your scaling.
- Then you just need to loop through your data, applying the scaling and plotting the data points.

You will also need to consider features such as multiple data ranges, point markers, data range colours, legend etc if your class is to be useful in the future.

Or you could search for a tool on nuget.

Comment: Your first point I know how to do. The scaling is difficult I think.Loop through the data and plot the lines I could do too

Comment: scaling is just "similar triangles".   Your range in the pixel universe is p  = maxaxis - minaxis, in the data it's r = maxrange - minrange.  That gives you a ratio p/r - so your plot point is minaxis + ratio * (val - minrange).
EDIT - (premature click)
Test it with axes and data that make it easy to do a sanity check on your graph. It seems complex but you just need to break it down a bit.